# how to add multiple functions to javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I am trying to add multiple functions to my variable.  However I am getting an error syntax error unexpected identifier.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var myVar = {
     func1:function(){

     }
     func2:function(data,cb){

     }
}
```

I want to be able to call these functions like:

```
 myVar.func1();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You left out the comma.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var myVar = {
     func1:function(){

     },
//    ^ you need a `,` here
     func2:function(data,cb){

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the comma.

```
var myVar = {
     func1:function(){

     },
     func2:function(data,cb){

     }
}
```